# checking empty String Java

Tags: java

I do have one validation issue and I don't know how to continue. The thing is that I am already checking if a string is empty (I guess) but it does not repeat the action.

I want the user types to be correct but it displays `Please try again`  and after that it continues to my next statement about the team description. Any ideas?

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the team : ");
team1.setTeamName(scanner.nextLine())
System.out.println("Enter the description of the team : ");

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {

    if (!isNullOrEmpty(teamName)) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Team name can't bee empty");
        System.out.println("Please try again");

public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
if (str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if you want something to repeat, you should use a **loop** or not? `while` loop until the condition is satisfied, e.g. `while(isNullOrEmpty(inputVariableHere)` { // scanner code here ...`

Comment: Hint: you could probably write a "validator" that returns a boolean based on some criteria that can be reused for a number of input types you want to validate before setting a class variable with it. This validator could be used in a loop to prohibit continuing to the next step.

Comment: i suggest using Apache Commons lang.  a Simple "StringUtils.isNotEmpty(...)" would be all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the method `setTeamName(String teamName)` to return a `boolean` indicating whether the name was correct or not.

```
public boolean setTeamName(String teamName) {
    if (!isNullOrEmpty(teamName)) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Team name can't bee empty");
        System.out.println("Please try again");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then check if the name was correct, and if not, repeat the action until it is correct.

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the team : ");

boolean valid;
do {
    valid = team1.setTeamName(scanner.nextLine())
} while (!valid);

System.out.println("Enter the description of the team : ");
```

Comment: @SebastianRubio great!, remember to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer so future readers know this solved the problem.